PyTest fixture : How to resolve FastAPI 'app' shortcut deprecated warning?
I am trying to solve one for all, this Warning while executing pytests:
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:680: 
DeprecationWarning: The 'app' shortcut is now deprecated. 
Use the explicit style 'transport=WSGITransport(app=...)' instead.
warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning)

I know that a similar question has been asked here:
How to write pytest tests for a FastAPI route involving dependency injection with Pydantic models using Annotated and Depends?
But still I cannot get how to avoid this warning.
I have this Python test fixture:
@pytest.fixture
def client(app: FastAPI) -> Generator:
    with TestClient(app, base_url="http://localhost") as client:
        yield client

But if I change this to the thing suggested in the link previously mentioned:
@pytest.fixture
def client()-> Generator:
  """Fixture to create a FastAPI test client."""
  # instead of app = app, use this to avoid the DeprecationWarning:
  with TestClient(transport=ASGITransport(app=app), base_url="http://localhost") as 
 client:
      yield client

My tests can't pass, and instead I have this new error:
TypeError: TestClient.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport'


There's difference between TestClient and AsyncClient. I would suggest that just cross verify that what you want use. Because AsyncClient has the transport parameter but TestClient don't have that.

Just upgrade FastAPI and Starlette to the latest versions. This problem is already fixed in Starlette 0.37.2.
If you use pip:
pip install --upgrade fastapi starlette

And use with TestClient(app, base_url="http://localhost") as client: as you did before.

Hello Thanks for the answer ! Actually I have poetry, so if I run poetry update starlette or poetry update fastapi it doesn't update because I have also py-de-logging that needs a version of starlette < 0.37.0 so I can't upgrade starlette apparently, but keep it to 0.36.3

In this case I think the only way is to ignore that warning

I encountered an issue where ignoring warnings didn't solve the problem. After trying several solutions, I found that the issue was due to incompatible versions of the FastAPI and Starlette packages. They both need to be compatible with each other. The following commands worked for me:
pip uninstall fastapi starlette pydantic -y
pip install fastapi==0.115.6
